# What does the $ operator do?

Tags: f#

When reading F# code on the net, the dollar operator pops up now and again, for example here: [Library patterns Multiple levels of abstraction](http://tomasp.net/blog/2015/library-layers/)

However, the [Symbol and Operator Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/) just says "No more information available".

What does the operator acutally do, and does anybody know where to find any actual documention on it?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't a standard operator.  Probably just a operator from some library

Comment: Maybe because it's *not* a language operator? You pointed to an article about a library that is `using the $ operator, which comes from the functional 3D DSL to put multiple objects together - `. That's a custom operator defined by a  library. Check the library's documentation

Comment: @JohnPalmer it's not, in fact it's explained in the linked articles

Comment: The declaration of that operator is [here](https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/blob/master/Talks%202013/Domain%20Specific%20Languages%20(NYC)/code/Functional3D/functional3d.fs#L195).

Comment: Of course, anyone can define an operator `$` that does anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard `$` operator in the language.

You can, of course define it.  The example you have linked uses this definition:

```
let ($) (DF a) (DF b) = DF (fun ctx -> 
  a(ctx)
  b(ctx) )
```

where `DF` is defined via:

```
type Drawing3D = DF of (Drawing3DContext -> unit)
```

---

Further, there are also special restrictions around the use of the `$` symbol in more complex operator names, for example the following:

```
let (<$>) f x = List.map f x
```

Will result in a compiler error.

> error FS0035: This construct is deprecated: '$' is not permitted as a
>   character in operator names and is reserved for future use